# Нахождение связных областей C++

Tags: c++, массивы, изображения

Нужно взять изображение (черно-белое), разбить его на двумерный массив пикселей и затем обработать его так, чтобы каждый отдельный объект был пронумерован. Проще говоря, посчитать количество объектов на картинке.

За основу я взял этот алгоритм:

```
if A = O 
  do nothing
else if (not B labeled) and (not C labeled)
  increment label numbering and label A
else if B xor C labeled
  copy label to A
else if B and C labeled
  if B label = C label
    copy label to A
  else
    copy either B label or C label to A
record equivalence of labels
```

И вот моя реализация в коде:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QImage>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    QImage image("2.bmp");
    int color[image.width()][image.height()];

    for(int y=0; y<image.height(); y++){
        for(int x=0; x<image.width();x++){

            QRgb rgb = image.pixel(x, y);
            color[x][y] = qRed( rgb );

        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<image.height(); j++){
        for(int i=0; i<image.width();i++){
            if (color[i][j] > 200 ){
                color[i][j] = 1;
            }else{
                color[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<image.width()-1;i++){
        for(int j=1; j<image.height()-1; j++){
            if (color[i][j] == 0 ){
                continue;
            }else if(color[i-1][j] != count && color[i][j-1] != count){
                count++;
                color[i][j] = count;
            }else if((color[i-1][j] = count)^(color[i][j-1] = count)){
                color[i][j] = count;
            }else if (color[i-1][j] == count && color[i][j-1] == count){
                if (color[i-1][j] == color[i][j-1]){
                    color[i][j] = count;
                }else{
                    color[i][j] = color[i-1][j];
                    color[i-1][j] = color[i][j-1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ofstream fout("d:\\filename.txt", ios::out);
    for(int j=0; j<image.height(); j++){
        for(int i=0; i<image.width();i++){
            fout << color[i][j];
        }
        fout << '\n';
    }

    cout << "Ready!";
    return 0;  
}
```

Но где-то затаилась ошибка, и я ее уже неделю не могу найти... Все перебираю и перебираю все возможные варианты,но ничего не выходит. Буду очень благодарен если кто-то поможет с этим вариантом или предложит свой.

Comment: А в отладчике что вы выяснили?

Comment: if((color[i-1][j] = count)^(color[i][j-1] = count))
тут у вас точно присваивание? По вашему алгоритму должно быть (color[i-1][j] ^ color[i][j-1]) == count нет?